# How to pass shell variables to awk in ksh shell script?

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

I want to know how to pass shell variables to awk..could some one please help.

m=10 // here is the shell vairable

```
awk -F, -v outfile="$outfile" '
    {
    printf("%14s Code %s %7s  %\047.2f\n"," ", $1," ",$2) >> outfile
    r[NR] = $1
    c[NR] = $3
   }
  END {printf("%14s Total Amount %7s %d \n "," "," ",$m) >> outfile

  }' trancumt.txt
```

please tell me do we have the way to do it or not..

Comment: What does `-v outfile="$outfile"` mean?

Comment: The -v option sets an awk variable (outfile in this case).

Comment: I expected the answer from OP, however why don't additionally passing `-v m="$m"` ???

Comment: If he changes it to use the -v option, then the "$" in "$m" would go away.

Comment: awk -F, -v outfile="$outfile", -v m="$m" ' i did this bef post...not worked

Comment: don't use a `,` between the `-v` options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple variables from the shell to awk using the option `-v` multiple times. The correct command would be:

```
awk -F, -v outfile="$outfile" -v m="$m" '<awk commands>'
```

Check the following example to see that it works:

```
m="10"
outfile="foo.bar"
awk -v m="$m" -v outfile="$outfile" 'BEGIN{print m, outfile; exit}'
```

Output:

```
10 foo.bar
```

Comment: how to print that hek.. its saying m: command not found...   m = 10
      awk -F, -v outfile="$outfile" -v m="$m" '  and printed like this.. printf("%14s Total Amount %7s %d \n "," "," ",$m)

Comment: thanks a lot.. i had space earlier it stoped me.. now its working

Answer (score 0):

Change the string slightly to allow substitution:

```
END {printf("%14s Total Amount %7s %d \n "," "," ",$m) >> outfile
```

to

```
END {printf("%14s Total Amount %7s %d \n "," "," ",'$m') >> outfile
```

Alternatively (see comments), change the line to

```
END {printf("%14s Total Amount %7s %d \n "," "," ",m) >> outfile
```

while adding an option

```
-v m=$m
```